# Need a PowerShell 2.0 replacement for string.replace method

Tags: powershell

I used the following PowerShell command as part of a post-build process that works well on recent versions of PowerShell:

```
powershell.exe –command "(Get-Content VSTEST.BAT).replace('__DLL_NAME__', 'SKCltMgrTestu.dll') | Set-Content 'C:\Builds\29\nSKEP\Dev_Continue\bin\VSTEST_SKCltMgrTest.BAT'
```

But I realized that I need an equivalent for a porduction machine which has only PowerShell 2.0 installed.
When executing the command on this machine, I get the following error:

```
C:\Builds\29\nSKEP\Dev_Continue\src\Tests\VSTest\SKCltMgrTest>powershell.exe –command "(Get-Content VSTEST.BAT).replace('__DLL_NAME__', 'SKCltMgrTestu.dll') | Set-Content 'C:\Builds\29\nSKEP\Dev_Conti
nue\bin\VSTEST_SKCltMgrTest.BAT'
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'replace'.
At line:1 char:33
+ (Get-Content VSTEST.BAT).replace <<<< ('__DLL_NAME__', 'SKCltMgrTestu.dll') | Set-Content 'C:\Builds\29\nSKEP\Dev_Continue\bin\VSTEST_SKCltMgrTest.BAT'
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (replace:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I suppose the required method was introduced only in later versions of PowerShell.

Is there an equivalent method of replacing a single occurence of a string in a text file with one-liner compatible with PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: The reason this fails, incidentally, is not because the method isn't there, but because later versions introduced the ability to invoke a method on an array of objects of the same type. Using `-replace` is the correct approach here, but if it didn't exist or wasn't sufficient, the PowerShell 1 equivalent of your code is `(Get-Content VSTEST.BAT) | Foreach { $_.replace(...) }`. PowerShell 3 (or 4, documentation on these things is terrible) just allows shorthand for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) `-replace` instead of the [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) `replace`method:

```
powershell.exe –command "(Get-Content VSTEST.BAT) -replace '__DLL_NAME__', 'SKCltMgrTestu.dll' | Set-Content 'C:\Builds\29\nSKEP\Dev_Continue\bin\VSTEST_SKCltMgrTest.BAT'
```